я хочу чтобы по нажатию кнопки на канвасе в нем спавнился объект но он спавнится просто в иерархииб а надо в канвасе
скрипт:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class SpawnObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject panel;
    public GameObject objectt;
    public Transform pos;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            panel.SetActive(true);

        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape)) 
        {
            panel.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
    public void SpawnObjects()
    {
        Instantiate(objectt, pos.position, Quaternion.identity);
    }

        
}


Хотеть - мало. Нужно еще эти свои хотелки донести до компилятора. А для этого, о боже, нужно почитать документацию...
Пользуйтесь: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html

документация ссылка
касательно этой ситуации:
объявляешь глобальную переменную например
public Transform canvas

и четвертый параметр в метод SpawnObjects() добавляешь.
Instantiate(objectt, pos.position, Quaternion.identity, сanvas);

